# How to use in-app payment without Google Play?

Tags: in-app-purchase

I downloaded the apk for the app Contacts Optimizer and had it installed via sideload. I would like to upgrade the app to PRO. This is done using an in-app payment. Trying to use this tells me that "Cannot initialize connection to in-app payment server, please try again later." I guess the reason is, because I have no Google App store on my phone. How can I use in-app payment without Google Play?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that Google billing is possible without the Google apps installed.

However, there are some apps that offer in-app purchase emulation. In most cases, they work and in addition, you don't have to pay. Lucky Patcher is an app which does in-app billing emulations. However, if you are not rooted, you need to rebuild the APK in which you want to use emulations and reinstall it.

Comment: I found http://lucky-patcher.de.uptodown.com/android, but I am not rooted. How do I do this APK rebuild etc.? It sound you have done it before. Could you give a detailed description please?

Comment: In the list of apps which appears when you open lucky patcher, select the app you want to patch. In the menu which appears then select create modified apk file and then "APK rebuild for in-app and lvl emulations" and then just apply. When the process is finished you will be informed where the modified apk is saved. Then you install it and just try the in-app purchase. *NOTE: when you install the modified apk file you will probably need to uninstall the existing installation of the app, because the package installer may refuse to install it because of a signature mismatch.