# How to restore purchases in an app that is no longer available on Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, restore, in-app-purchase

A good friend of mine played a game called "Cordy" years back. The first three levels in Cordy could be played for free, the ones after that you had to unlock via In-App purchase. Back then, she decided to buy premium. Fast forward to today: Her childhood game is no longer available on the Play Store, and when you install the APK provided by a third party, it comes without the stuff unlocked. Attempting to restore previous purchases doesn't do anything.

Is there anything I can do to get it to work so that she can play the full game again?

If I have to mess around with the APK file, that would be fine too.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to use in-app payment without Google Play?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/169394/44325).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patching the app with a tool called Lucky Patcher achieved the desired results.